# Where to specify whether it's a GET or POST?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

When I create a new Google Cloud function, the default code given is:

```
const functions = require('@google-cloud/functions-framework');

functions.http('helloHttp', (req, res) => {
 res.send(`Hello ${req.query.name || req.body.name || 'World'}!`);
});
```

However, in this [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/local-development-with-cloud-functions#3), the function is specified as:

```
exports.validateTemperature = async (req, res) => {
 try {
   if (req.body.temp < 100) {
     res.status(200).send("Temperature OK");
   } else {
     res.status(200).send("Too hot");
   }
 } catch (error) {
   //return an error
   console.log("got error: ", error);
   res.status(500).send(error);
 }
};
```

What is the difference between the two? How do they work in the bigger scheme of things?

In the second example, the code is listening for a Http POST request. Where is this specified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Functions Framework**

[Functions Framework](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-nodejs) turns a Cloud Functions snippet into a workable server. It's kind of like register a handler function to an express router, and run the express app behind the scenes.

The main use case is local development and migrant to App Engine or other services. They both need to start a HTTP server, and functions framework does that.

**Express**

Node.js runtime explains your code snippet using [Express framework](https://expressjs.com/zh-tw/4x/api.html#req.body).
The `validateTemperature` accepts all HTTP methods.

We often filter HTTP methods by a router. Although you can do it in with `req.method`. And router, web server level is what you don't want to reapeat again and again.

If you want to split requests by method when buiding an API service, you could consider let Cloud Endpoints or some API Gateway stands before your functions.

Answer (score 2):

Through the two methods you exposed the result is the same, a HTTP Path is used to receive the Request and Response objects.

Inside the Request object, you may find the Body (usually filled in POST & PUT requests but not limited to) and the Method (GET, POST, PUT, etc).

Therefore, your Cloud Function code will be used with both a GET and a POST call in either solution.